# How to wait disappear spinner on puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

how do I wait for the spinner to disappear and then click on a button.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RZO8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to see how to identify the overlaying DIV and then use [waitForSelector](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) passing the `hidden` options.

```
await page.waitForSelector('.some-div-selector', { hidden: true});
```